# Modular jar of GSON

Tags: java, maven, module, gson

I recently migrated one of my personnal project from java 8 to java 10.
But then I ran into this warning which, as a warning hater, I had to fix.

> Name of automatic module 'gson' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name.

I checked the jar file I'm retrieving with maven and indeed, it's not a modular jar (there's no `module-info.class` in it).
So I checked GSON github and found out that there IS a `module-info.java` file for GSON.

So my questions are:

- Why don't maven give me a modular jar? I find it very surprising considering modular jar can be used as regular jar when placed on the class path. Is it a maven thing?
- What's the best way to retrieve a modular jar for GSON? (or even a JMOD file). Build the jar myself from github sources? Use an alternative to maven?

Additional informations:

- IDE: Eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0)
- JDK: 10.0.1
- maven denpendency:

  com.google.code.gson
    gson
    2.8.5

Answer (score 2):

You're right, version 2.8.5 of Gson does contain a module-info but according to [this issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1315) it was in the wrong place. Although it's fixed now (1 month ago), a new release containing that fix has not yet been released.

I guess we'll have to wait.